# Проблема с https протоколом

Tags: wordpress, https, редирект

Доброго денёчка! Столкнулся с такой проблемой. После установки вордпресса на хостинг, когда захожу на сайт, браузер ругается на https протокол. Пробовал с 4х компов - везде тоже самое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нажимаю "дополнительно" и перехожу на сайт игнорируя предупреждение браузера.
Но при входе в админку вордпресса, выдает такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял, включен https протокол, но он не настроен правильно, из - за чего браузер ругается. Помогите решить проблему! Как сделать что бы сайт открывался не через https а через http и не ругался браузер?

Или просто можно ли сделать чтоб бы не ругался браузер?

Думал что в файле htaccess стоит редирект с http на https, но его там нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, комрады!

Comment: Напишите в поддержку хостинга, пусть проверят, может у них автоматом включена переадресация на https

Comment: Заходил в лк хостинга, видел там пункт что никаких редиректов для домена не включено. Ещё варианты?

Comment: это может от лк и не зависеть, надо им написать чтобы в настройках сервера проверили

Comment: Попробую, спасибо за ответ. 

И все же рассчитываю на альтернативные варианты решения данной проблемы от знающих мастеров.

Comment: А почистить куки/кеш браузера / сменить браузер / приватный режим и зайти по http? Ну или тут http://bertal.ru/ проверить ответ севера на запрос сайта по http

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но решение нашёл самостоятельно.
Все таки в настройках хостинга крылась проблема.